# Django custom admin admin.site.register + admin.site.unregister conflicting AlreadyRegistered + NotRegistered on 1st HTTP GET (Apache + mod WSGI)

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

During the 1st HTTP GET (right after the WSGI in daemon mode is reloaded), admin.site.unregister throws a NotRegistered exception, but admin.site.register throws an AlreadyRegistered exception (catch-22?) However, on the subsequent HTTP GETs, everything loads just fine with no error.

Setup:

- Django 1.3
- Apache 2.2
- CentOS

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.sites', #(this didn't seem to make a difference)
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'base',
    'sample',
    'reports',
    'south',
)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin

class Company(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class CompanyUser(models.Model):
  company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class CompanyUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = CompanyUser
  max_num = 1
  can_delete = False

class CompanyUserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
  inlines = [ CompanyUserInline ]

# STUCK HERE !!
try:
  admin.site.unregister(User)
  # throws NotRegistered at / The model User is not registered
except:
  admin.site.register(User, CompanyUserAdmin)
  # throws AlreadyRegistered at / The model User is already registered
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer from mlavin on freenode's #django

> you are defining this in your models.py rather than admin.py (which is
>   fine) but if you have any place in your code which does import * on
>   that models file it will execute the register calls again

Moving what belongs in admin.py to admin.py (from models.py) solved it! In my defense though, I inherited the code base - I'm not sure why I would put this snippet in models.py instead of admin.py.

Interesting to note: while this problem never cropped up locally for me via "manage.py runserver" but only when I deployed via Apache + WSGI, one other person mentioned they were able to reproduce it locally. Weird.

But case closed.

Comment: Stumbled upon this through Google (small world).  Thanks for answering your own question.

Comment: Brilliant answer. I can't give a +n to this. :(

Answer (score 0):

My problem was:

> I want to edit in User(ex: add mobile) with MyUser(AbstarctUser) custom model(in model.py) and in my admin.py file script first unregister my model  MyUser and then register it but Django not register my custom MyUser model by default,

**So in my case there is no need to unregister my custom module first just register is sufficient.**